# Can we use regex to concat chars at different index

Tags: regex

Say for example here is a string input:

```
D8DB2F1F0F21R123
```

We need to extract chars at index(assumption starting index is 0): 4,8,6,1 ie: '2','0','1','8' and concat them.
Final output should be: `2018`

Can we achieve the above desired result, just by a regex ?

Comment: Do you use linux ? windows ?

Comment: `^.(.).{2}(.).(.).(.)` but I would urge you not to use regex.

Comment: thanks @GillesQuenot for correcting the typos and to your question, its for linux.

Comment: @anubhava : the reason for regex is to extend the freedom of parsing the string to end user, while the service end just computes the regex to get desired result.

Comment: @ctwheels : I too had tried the similar approach:: ^.{4}(.)...(.)..(.), but struggled to traverse in reverse direction to fetch the last desired digit.

Answer (score 0):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
$ x=D8DB2F1F0F21R123
$ echo ${x:4:1}${x:8:1}${x:6:1}${x:1:1}
2018
```